# Why JPA FindAll coming back with correct size of list but all elements are null

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Hi I am trying to develop a small JPA application . I have a simple `findAll` method in my `service class` . But the result is coming back with correct size of number of columns , but all elements are `NULL` . I just put two records in Table . My List size shows as 2 but all elements are NULL .

**Entity Class:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "IC_ERROR")
@Entity
public class ICError implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EVENT_ID")
    String id;
}
```

**Service class:**

```
@Data
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ICService {

    @Autowired
    ICErrorRepository iCErrorRepository;

    public List<ICError> errors() {
        List<ICError> icErrorQ = ICErrorRepository.findAll(); // Size is getting as 2 but all
        elements are null.
        return icErrorQ;
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface ICErrorRepository extends JpaRepository<ICError, String> {
}
```

Comment: I can see only one column mapped with attribute in your entity class, is that coming as blank?

Comment: Check the generate SQL statement

Comment: `ICErrorRepository.findAll()` is this working ? it should be `iCErrorRepository.findAll()`. Please change the code accordingly and also share the debugged results by enabling `spring.jpa.show-sql: true` in application.properties

Comment: Sorry that was a typo . I changed it in Question. The Generated SQL is giving me the results. Its a plain select statement.

Comment: Can you try without implementing the `Serializable` interface or if you need to implement it try by declaring a `serialVersionUID` for your class [default: `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`].

Comment: tried that but no luck

Comment: what is the database you are using?

Comment: I am using Oracle  DB